# FAILED (remote: 'Command not allowed') fastboot: error: Command failed

Tags: android, root, huawei-mobile-services, root-access

So im trying to root my phone (huawei p9 lite) im trying to write the img file (im in fastboot) and it shows me the error above this is the string
fastboot flash boot magisk_patched-26000_Y0A6V.img
Sending 'boot' (15970 KB)                          OKAY [  0.414s]
Writing 'boot'                                     FAILED (remote: 'Command not allowed')
fastboot: error: Command failed

tried diffrent cable and reinstalling the drivers.